# MegaSync app won't start on startup

Tags: startup, upstart, mega

On the application settings I have checked the option to start app on startup:

[image]

Also on the start-up application preferences, the app is checked:

[image].

But since this morning, the app won't automatically start when I login. I checked `/var/log/syslog` and there is no error regarding this app. Also, if I open in manually, it works.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This app got updated a few days ago. As such, it might be a bug.

Workarounds:

- If you use it all the time, then do not close it at the end of your session and it will start automatically in your next session (at least it works for me, in Xubuntu 14.04).
- If you do not use it all the time, then create a file to run after you login. Create a `.desktop` file with the following content:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Start MEGAsync
  Exec=megasync
  Type=Application
  Terminal=false
  ```

Save this file where all your post-login startup files are stored: `~/.config/autostart`. Now, it will start every time you log in.